# Are ubuntu Snappy and "Traditional Ubuntu Core" now just one?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Quoting from http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2015/01/snappy-vs-apt-get-ubuntu-matrix.html:

> Q: I'm looking for the smallest possible Ubuntu image that still
>   supports apt-get... A: You want our Traditional Ubuntu Core. This is
>   often useful in building Docker and LXC containers.
>
> Q: I'm building the next wearable IoT device/drone/robot, and perhaps
>   deploying a fleet of atomically updated micro-services to the cloud...
>   A: You want Snappy Ubuntu Core.

There seems to be two flavors of ubuntu... an "Ubuntu core" which supports apt-get and the snappy which doesnt.

Where can we download the "Traditional Ubuntu Core" from? Did it cease to exist and is now the same as the snappy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, in the past Core and Snappy were two distinct OS flavors. If you dig through old releases, there's [core images](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntu-core/releases/13.10/release/), but no snappy.

Dustin's blog dates to January 22, 2015. In [this techcrunch article](https://techcrunch.com/2014/12/09/canonical-launches-snappy-edition-of-ubuntu-core-for-container-farms/) from December 9, 2014 the author refers to the two as distinct versions:

> A few years ago, Ubuntu launched a minimalist “core” version of its
>   operating system for embedded systems. Today, it is launching an alpha
>   version of its new “snappy” edition of Ubuntu Core with transactional
>   updates that is specifically geared toward container farms, large
>   Docker deployments and platform-as-a-service environments

Since around  mid-2015, Ubuntu Core ceased to exist and now "Snappy" and "Snappy Core" are used interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, marked as accepted. As a side question is there a lightest alternative i can use instead of ubuntu server that could still provide apt-get etc..?

Comment: @Onitlikesonic Mark Shuttleworth has mentioned in the past that eventually Snappy should have apt-get and dpkg support added, but  for now , I'd say Ubuntu Mate for Arm is the best alternative. Note that Mate is community-maintained version, it's not "officially" supported by Canonical.